# Why OrderByDescending not recognized as build method

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private static void findNewestFile(List<string> list)
{
    foreach (string dir in list)
    {
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        var file = directory.GetFiles("*.doc").OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
    }
}
```

This function received list of folders I try to find the newest file from each directory but the method `OrderByDescending` not recognized and the compiler error is:

> *Error    1   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending' and no extension method 'OrderByDescending'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most probably you are missing `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 6):

Your code file need to include this:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: While I most often run into Linq issues because, as Karl stated above, using System.Linq is missing.  I also have recreated it by using a templated class derived from a non-typed IEnumerable list.  Even having an IEnumerable<T> for the templated type, for some reason wasn't informing c# 8.0 that I should be able to do type specific LINQ.  I ended up removing the interface from abstract base class and added a public accessor to get an IEnumerable... which worked around the problem.  Just saying in case anyone else similarly ends up at this same page for the same reason.

Comment: I ran into this issue when the keySelector function passed to OrderBy (resp. OrderByDescending) (here, the lambda "f => f.LastWriteTime") selected a method of the target class, mistaking it for a property. E.g. "f => f.Count" where Count is not a property, but a method on the type of the parameter f.

Comment: Why visual studio doesn't show suggestions to include "using System.Linq;"