# How to "query" List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, list

Say I have,

```
List<ExampleType> example;
```

Somewhere it has been populated with let's say 10 objects of ExampleType.

ExampleType looks like this:

```
class ExampleType 
{
    public string ID;
    public string name;
    //etc.


   //Some other members..
}
```

Now, how would I go through the List `example`, and query only `ExampleType` objects that has the name e.g. Peter and store it in another List, like:

```
List<ExampleType> peterExamples = example. //some query functionality that I can't find
```

I have tried `example.AsQueryable`. But couldn't get it to work. I suspect I need some LINQ to query the list maybe?

Comment: Make sure you include a `using` directive with `System.Linq` if you want the extension methods (e.g. `Where`, `Select`, `Distinct`, etc.) to be available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all `ExampleType` elements with `name == "Peter"` like this:

```
var peterExamples = example.Where(e => e.name == "Peter");
```

That will return an `IEnumerable`, if you need a `List` you can convert it to one by calling `ToList()`.

```
var peterList = peterExamples.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick

```
var peterList = example.Where(x => x.name == "Peter").ToList();
```

In this case the list is only of `ExampleType` hence no query for only `ExampleType` is needed.  If you were faced with a `List<object>` though and needed to only run this on `ExampleType` then you could do the following

```
var peterList = example
  .OfType<ExampleType>()
  .Where(x => x.name == "Peter")
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
List<ExampleType> peterExamples = example.Where(t=>t.name == "Peter").ToList();
```

Or you could use query syntax:

```
List<ExampleType> peterExamples = (
   from item in example
   where item.name == "peter"
   select item ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
peterExamples.Where(p=>p.name== "Peter").ToList()
peterExamples.Where(p=>p.name.Contains("Peter")).ToList();//to search for LIKE '%Peter%'
```

Answer (score 1):

[LINQ (Enumerable) extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used on any `IEnumerable<T>` (`IQueryable<T>` is a subtype of `IEnumerable<T>`), which includes `List<T>`.

If intellisense is "not working", or there are errors such as "Where/AsQueryable not recognized as .. method", then the code needs to import the extension methods (e.g. [`using System.Linq`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537571/2864740)) so that the are available.

See [LINQ (Language-Integrated Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) for further usage and information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without LINQ using `List<T>`'s `FindAll` method:

`var peterExamples = example.FindAll(item => item.name == "Peter");`

Answer (score 0):

You must also have this using statement for the Linq queries to work.

```
using System.Linq;
```